# Removing qoute marks from CSV and changing column names accordingly using batch?

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have a lot of CSV files that contain 100 000+ rows and their structure looks similar to this:

```
Time,Longitude,Latitude,R,E,M
2016-01-01M12:01:01,39.92234,52.61532,"-11.5,-20.4",-4.5,No
2016-01-01M12:01:01,39.92238,52.61562,"-10.1,-12.7,-9.2,-7.7",,No
2016-01-01M12:01:02,39.92239,52.61552,"-12.1,-12.4",-3.9,No
2016-01-01M12:01:03,39.92248,52.61562,"-3.1,-1.9,-8.2",,No
```

and so on...

What I would like to do is to get the max number of values between the quotes, change the column names accordingly.

For example the second row has the max number of values between the quotes so R should be changed to `R1,R2,R3,R4`, and finally remove quote marks using batch file.

So the result should look like this:

```
Time,Longitude,Latitude,R1,R2,R3,R4,E,M
2016-01-01M12:01:01,39.92234,52.61532,-11.5,-20.4,,,-4.5,No
2016-01-01M12:01:01,39.92238,52.61562,-10.1,-12.7,-9.2,-7.7,,No
2016-01-01M12:01:02,39.92239,52.61552,-12.1,-12.4,,,-3.9,No
2016-01-01M12:01:03,39.92248,52.61562,-3.1,-1.9,-8.2,,,No
```

and so on...

I've been trying to find any example how to do this for almost a couple of weeks but without success. Maybe someone can help me out?

Comment: What do you mean by "... using batch file"?  What you need to do is straightforward enough (two passes through the CSV file: on the first pass, parse the CSV, and get the max.# of values; on the second pass rewrite the CSV in the format you want).  But the batch language that comes with the CMD command processor is probably not the right tool for the job.

Comment: I would like to have a double clickable file that would change the column names as described in my first post. So far I have a batch file that joins all the files and now I would like it to rename the columns. This is the file I currently have: 
echo on
title CSV
copy *.csv all.csv
pause

Comment: The next step is to add a line to your batch file to execute a program that will make your desired changes to the file.  You can write this program in almost any language, but if you are running Windows and want to use a scripting language, JScript or VBScript might be reasonable options.

Comment: Please regard that StackOverflow is not a free code/script writing service! You have to try it on your own, and when stuck, come back here and ask a specific question. Please read the [tour] and also these articles: [ask]; [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you did not show any own efforts to solve the task, I decided to provide a solution, because it seems to be a challenging project. So here is what I came up with:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~1" & rem // (file to process; use first command line parameter)

rem // Initialise variables:
set /A "MAX=0" & rem // (maximum number of items in between quoted group)
set /A "POS=0" & rem // (position of quoted group)

rem // Pass 1: count maximum number of items within quotes:
set /A "COUNT=0, INDEX=0"
for /F usebackq^ skip^=1^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%_FILE%") do (
    for %%I in (%%L) do (
        set "QUOTED=%%I"
        set "UNQUOTED=%%~I"
        set /A "INDEX+=1"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        if not "!QUOTED!"=="!UNQUOTED!" (
            if !POS! leq 0 (
                endlocal & set /A "POS=INDEX"
            ) else endlocal
            set "COUNT="
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            set "ITEM=%%~I"
            for %%J in ("!ITEM:,="^,"!") do (
                if not defined COUNT endlocal
                set /A "COUNT+=1"
            )
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            if !MAX! lss !COUNT! (
                endlocal & set /A "MAX=COUNT"
            ) else endlocal
        ) else endlocal
    )
)

rem // Build separators butter:
set "SEPB=" & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%E in (1,1,%MAX%) do (
    set "SEPB=!SEPB!,"
)
endlocal & set "SEPB=%SEPB%"

rem // Process header:
set /A "INDEX=0"
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%_FILE%") do (
    set "COLL=,"
    for %%I in (%%L) do (
        set /A "INDEX+=1" & set "ITEM=%%~I"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        if !INDEX! equ !POS! (
            for /L %%K in (1,1,%MAX%) do (
                set "COLL=!COLL!!ITEM!%%K,"
            )
        ) else (
            set "COLL=!COLL!!ITEM!,"
        )
        for /F "delims=" %%E in (""!COLL!"") do (
            endlocal & set "COLL=%%~E"
        )
    )
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo/!COLL:~1^,-1!
    endlocal
    goto :NEXT
)
:NEXT

rem // Pass 2: expand items in between quotes:
for /F usebackq^ skip^=1^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%_FILE%") do (
    set "LINE=%%L" & set "COLL=,"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for %%I in ("!LINE:,="^,"!") do (
        endlocal
        set "SEPS=%SEPB%" & set "QUOTED=%%~I" & set "UNQUOTED="
        for %%J in (%%~I) do (
            set "UNQUOTED=%%~J"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            if "!QUOTED!"=="!UNQUOTED!" (
                set "COLL=!COLL!!QUOTED!," & set "SEPS="
            ) else (
                set "COLL=!COLL!!UNQUOTED!," & set "SEPS=!SEPS:~,-1!"
            )
            for /F "delims=" %%E in (""!COLL!"") do (
                for /F "delims=" %%F in (""!SEPS!"") do (
                    endlocal & set "COLL=%%~E" & set "SEPS=%%~F"
                )
            )
        )
        if not defined QUOTED set "SEPS=,"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        for /F "delims=" %%K in (""!COLL!!SEPS!"") do (
            endlocal & set "COLL=%%~K"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        )
    )
    echo/!COLL:~1^,-1!
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Assuming the batch script is saved as `resolve-csv.bat` in the current directory and the CSV file to process is called `D:\Test\data.csv`, type the following into Windows Command Prompt:

```cmd
resolve-csv.bat "D:\Test\data.csv"
```

To store the output into another CSV file, for instance, `D:\Test\result.csv`, type this:

```cmd
resolve-csv.bat "D:\Test\data.csv" > "D:\Test\result.csv"
```

Comment: Thank you, I REALLY appreciate it. Did not expect it to be such a long script... Although I get an error when running it (The system cannot find the file) I'll try to figure it out myself. I will report back once I get it to work. Thank you once again.

Comment: Did you notice that the script expects the input CSV file as the first command line parameter?

Comment: Ok, I have been trying to get this work but no success. I have inserted the csv file path into different positions between "@echo off" and "rem // Initialise variables:" but still get "The system cannot find file". The csv file just opens and that's it. Is my approach correct (obviously not) or how should the path be inserted?

Comment: What do you mean by *"the CSV file just opens"*??

Comment: For example if I insert the path C:\Users\User\Desktop\file.csv between `"setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion"` and `"rem // Define constants here:"` then file.csv just pops up and when I close it I can still see the message "The system cannot find file". So I am not quite sure where should I insert the input CSV file path...

Comment: Read my [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49367965/2). There is no need to modify the batch file. If you do want to put the CSV file path therein, replace `set "_FILE=%~1"` by `set "_FILE=D:\Test\data.csv"`...

Comment: Yes, now it is working, thank you! Unfortunately the result is not quite what was expected - column "Time" has numbers (Time1,Time2,Time3,Time4,Time5,Time6,Time7,Time8) instead of column "R" and also there are double quotes now. I will try to figure out what is going on there.

Comment: Is the format of the input file deviating from the one you specified in your question?

Comment: Sorry, sorry, this code works! Thank you a lot! I must have messed up something when I tried it first time with my test file. Sorry for the confusion once again. Although I did not ask this in my first question: if the file has for example quotes also in column E and M then will it be enough if I modify the  "Pass 1" part in this code?

Comment: No problem! Well, it just modifed the script (pass 1) in order to handle also empty values in the quoted part correctly, so now it should work without any further edit...